# EditText padding attribute does not work for API 21 and 22

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding, android-version

Setting padding value for my `EditText`s. However It doesn't work both *21* and *22* api versions. However, It works perfectly for *19*, *23*, *24*.

**Here is my codes**:

```
<style name="LoginEditTextStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/login_text_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/login_text_padding</item>
    </style>
```

This my edittext in the layout xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_container_child_view_top_margin"
            android:alpha="0">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_username_editText"
                style="@style/LoginEditTextStyle"
                android:hint="@string/user_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The result for 21 api version

[image]

for 24 api version

[image]

I know there is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008040#makechanges) of edittext/spinner view to set padding value from xml.

I know there is some solution for this issue such as setting padding values programmaticaly. But It doesn't work for me.

for example : [this accepted solution doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701155/4606266)

```
int paddingLeft = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int paddingRight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 55, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int paddingTop = editText.getPaddingTop();
        int paddingBottom = editText.getPaddingBottom();
        editText.setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
```

Comment: does applying padding directly to edittext working?

Comment: nope!! It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. `paddingLeft` doesn't work on Android 5.1.1 devices.

Add `paddingStart` instead which solved the problem for me.

Please give it a try.